# Por que todos los elementos del arrayList que agrego quedan iguales

Tags: java, arraylist

Quiero crear un arrayList que su tamaño sea ingresado por el usuario, pero todos los elementos que ingresan en el arrayList quedan exactamente iguales, este es mi codigo:
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
List departamentos = new ArrayList<>();

```
    int numeroDepartamentosLista;
    System.out.println("Cuantos departamentos desea agregar?");
    numeroDepartamentosLista = entrada.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroDepartamentosLista; i++){
        int conteoDepartamentos=i+1;
        Departamento departamento = new Departamento();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de municipios del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setNumeroMunicipios(entrada.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la extención de tierra (mt2) del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setExtencionTierra(entrada.nextDouble());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de habitantes del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setNumeroHabitantes(entrada.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la temperatura en grados celsius del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setTemperaturaGradosCelcius(entrada.nextDouble());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el indicativo telefonico del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setIndicativoTelefonico(entrada.nextInt());
        departamentos.add(departamento);
        
    }
    
    for (int k = 0; k < departamentos.size(); k++){
        System.out.println(departamentos);
    }
```

Comment: Tu error esta en que estas imprimiendo el objeto lista y no su contenido, para solucionarlo accede al contenido con el metodo get(index) del array list **System.out.println(departamentos.get(k).getTemperatura());**

Comment: Aaaa sisi, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay varios puntos que hay que tener en cuenta en tu consulta, y uno de ellos es muy importante (fíjate en los comentarios que he metido en el código):

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numeroDepartamentosLista;
    System.out.println("Cuantos departamentos desea agregar?");
    ArrayList<Departamento> departamentos = new ArrayList<Departamento>();
    numeroDepartamentosLista = entrada.nextInt();
    // La DECLARACIÓN de variables SIEMPRE FUERA del for, 
    //de lo contrario irás duplicando variables y ocupando memoria innecesaria, 
    //provocando incluso que al equipo que lo corra le pueda dar un infartito.
    Departamento departamento;
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroDepartamentosLista; i++){
        int conteoDepartamentos=i+1;
        // La INICIALIZACIÓN de variables SÍ que PUEDES hacerla DENTRO en un for,
        // ya que no declaras nada nuevo ni consumes memoria extra, 
        // de hecho, es buena práctica, ya que en java podrías sobrescribir
        // todo por error por referencia
        departamento = new Departamento();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de municipios del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setNumeroMunicipios(entrada.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la extención de tierra (mt2) del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setExtencionTierra(entrada.nextDouble());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de habitantes del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setNumeroHabitantes(entrada.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la temperatura en grados celsius del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setTemperaturaGradosCelcius(entrada.nextDouble());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el indicativo telefonico del departamento "+conteoDepartamentos);
        departamento.setIndicativoTelefonico(entrada.nextInt());
        departamentos.add(departamento);
        
    }
    // El system.out.println está preparado para pintar Strings, 
    // no objetos enteros, por eso parece que son todos iguales, 
    // pero en realidad no lo son, tal como demuestra este código
    for (int k = 0; k < departamentos.size(); k++){
        System.out.println("Departamento " + k+1);
        System.out.println("Numero Municipios: " + departamentos.get(k).getNumeroMunicipios());
        System.out.println("Extencion tierra: " + departamentos.get(k).getExtencionTierra());
        System.out.println("Numero Habitantes: " + departamentos.get(k).getNumeroHabitantes());
        System.out.println("Temperatura grados Celsius: " + departamentos.get(k).getTemperaturaGradosCelcius());
        System.out.println("Indicativo telefonico: " + departamentos.get(k).getIndicativoTelefonico());
    }
    entrada.close();
```